# Movie with a giant white room full of hundreds of humanoid monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie

On a DVD or VHS before a movie, I saw the trailer for this movie.

In the trailer there's a big white room with hundreds of humanoid monsters inside.

I think it might be a comedy because for some reason someone gets thrown into the giant white room from high up and gets attacked.

I think it was an early 2000s movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any idea what the movie you were watching was?  Was the trailer live-action or animated? In English or another language?

Comment: How was they attacked? Weapons, bare hands? Was that some kind of fighting arena?

Comment: Resident Evil: Afterlife is what immediately springs to mind; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J58VPpPrmQU (warning: NFSW - Gory)

Comment: I can't get the idea out of my head that the "humanoid monsters" were actually tired starlings.

Comment: possibly cabin in the woods if they are all in individual cells

Comment: The scene has two people being thrown into the white room and it was live action